# My email is not considered valid

Tags: support

My email, at least on super user is not loger considered valid. It contains 10 letters after which is 1 number, at symbol (@) and gmail.com. It was considered valid before.

Any idea why does it happen?

**EDIT**: I get the message when I post new question (like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/184926/winrm-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it)). However afterwards I did not receive any error when I simply marked checkbox after posting question.
The error was reproducable in sense that after rechecking box after error it was reported again. I haven't change the email and it was fetched from database.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to where your getting the invalid message?

Comment: I've replied by editing post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like SU doesn't think you verified your email address -- have you gotten any emails from SU at all? You should, at least, have gotten one of those "verify email address" messages; if you reply to that, you should be good. Otherwise, take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/invalid-email-for-valid-email-address.